# Charged CFT observables and AdS/CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I have a simple question regarding the holographic dictionary when mapping operators on the CFT side to those in AdS.

One piece of the dictionary is that a global symmetry maps onto a gauge symmetry in the bulk. So if I have operators charged under the global symmetry in the CFT then naively I would assume these are operators charged under the gauge symmetry in the bulk. However, since gauge symmetry is a redundant description we should also restrict to gauge singlet operators, at least to define observables in correlation functions. It seems theres an asymmetry here, all the charged operators on the CFT side are good observables, but only those in the singlet representation map to gauge invariant operators in the bulk.

Is it that the operators in the bulk are also all charged under a global symmetry (assuming we're working in the classical limit on the gravity side so it remains unbroken)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me work in the usual limit where a classical theory of gravity maps to a strongly interacting conformal field theory (CFT) with some color like parameter $N$ that is taken to be very large.  In this limit, a central statement of the correspondence is that a generating function for correlation functions on the CFT side is given by the on-shell gravitational action evaluated with certain boundary conditions for the fields.  These boundary conditions are interpreted as sources for operators on the dual CFT side.  In other words, on the CFT side, I've added something like $\int \phi_0 O$ to the action where $O$ is my operator for which I want to compute correlation functions and $\phi_0$ is a source.  On the gravity side, $\phi_0$ is then interpreted as a boundary condition for some gravity field $\phi$.  I use this boundary condition to solve Einstein's equations and then use that solution to evaluate the action.  I get a schematic relation of the form
$$
S_{\rm grav}(\phi_0) = W_{\rm CFT}(\phi_0)
$$
where 
$$
{\delta^n W_{\rm CFT} \over \delta \phi_0^n} = \langle O^n \rangle.
$$

From this point of view, there is then no obvious impediment to considering an operator $O$ that is charged under some global symmetry on the CFT side.  Indeed, that symmetry is gauged in the bulk, and there will be some corresponding field $\phi$ that is also charged under that gauge symmetry.  Nevertheless, I can solve Einstein plus Maxwell or Einstein plus Yang-Mills equations in the bulk with the specified boundary value $\phi_0$.  Even if $\phi$ transforms under the gauge symmetry, we usually restrict to local gauge transformations that fall to zero at the boundary.  Thus $\phi_0$ will be a well defined quantity.

Added: Following the comments below, it seems important to add the following.  While the gauge transformations that fall off at the boundary are redundant, the gauge transformations that don't fall off at the boundary are not gauged and are not redundant.  They form an asymptotic symmetry group of the gravity theory.  They act to change the state of the CFT and also (at a classical level) to change the solution to Einstein's equations.  There is a matching between the global symmetry group of the CFT and the asymptotic symmetries on the gravity side.

One well cited example of an AdS/CFT system with a field that transforms under a global symmetry is the holographic superconductor: http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1563.

Comment: I don't think I was being clear in the question. The problem is not about to compute something in AdS/CFT when the CFT has a global symmetry (the prototypical example of N=4 SYM has a R-symmetry).

The question I had concerned the interpretation. In a QFT with a global symmetry the Hilbert space gives a representation of the group while gauge symmetries correspond to a a relabeling of states. So one interpretation of AdS/CFT is that the Hilbert spaces of the theories should match (see e.g. http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~jaredk/AdSCFTCourseNotesPublic.pdf).

Comment: The issue is then that the Hilbert space on the CFT side appears much larger. We have any representation of the group, while in the bulk this theory is gauged and naively we're restricted to the singlet sector.

I think one resolution to this issue is that if the bulk dual had a confining gauge theory sector, we wouldn't have conserved currents for the global symmetry in the bulk (they would have some anomalous dimensions). On the other hand if have a conserved current, this should be dual to a deconfined phase in the bulk.

Comment: Why do you say the Hilbert space should be much larger?  We should restrict to gauge transformations that vanish on the boundary, where the field theory "lives".  The "large" gauge transformations which do affect boundary quantities generate the global symmetry of the CFT and are not redundant in the same way that the "small" gauge transformations that vanish at the boundary are.

Comment: One more comment: you said in your question that you would naively assume charged operators in the CFT correspond to charged operators in gravity.  I think that's not right.  The boundary values of the gravity fields act as sources for the operators in the CFT.

Comment: 1) In the CFT all operators charged under the global symmetry belong to the Hilbert space. When we gauge a symmetry we project to the singlet sector, reducing its size. This is what happens in the bulk so naively the Hilbert space should be much smaller. I'm not sure the relevance of the gauge transformations unless you're implying the large gauge transformations are not redundant in the bulk.
2) You stated also that an operator charged under a global symmetry is dual to an operator that transforming under the gauge symmetry. That's also what I was stating.

Comment: 1) The large gauge transformations are not redundant in the bulk.  If they were, one would find unpleasant things, e.g. two CFTs at different chemical potential are gauge equivalent.  2) I stated that the boundary value of a gravity field sources an operator in the CFT.  I said nothing about quantum operators on the gravity side.  If you would like, you could promote the classical field to a quantum operator on the gravity side.  Even then, one needs to make a careful distinction between the boundary value of this quantum operator and its bulk behavior.

Comment: 1) I agree about the large gauge transformations not being redundant. They label different vacua. 2) Yes you were talking classically and different BCs correspond to different CFTs (i.e. with the O(N) models) but the duality should hold at a quantum level and you can use CFT correlation functions to study the interior of AdS. I don't think this discussions is relevant though.

For the Hilbert spaces to match there must be a matching of global symmetries (i.e. SU(4) R-symmetry in N=4 SYM and SO(6) for AdS5). I think this is usually assumed and where my question stems from.

Comment: But if you agree about the large gauge transformations, then I think you also agree that the global symmetries match?

Comment: I don't see that it follows. A SU(2) gauge theory in 3+1d has a set of large gauge transformations indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$. The global symmetry transformations are constant shifts relating different vacua. The boundary theory has an SU(2) global symmetry. They're different symmetry groups.

Comment: I realize now that I'm perhaps using "large gauge transformation" in a nonstandard way.  In the path integral for the gravity theory (whatever that may be), I always understood that one should fix boundary conditions for the gauge field at the boundary of AdS such that what I'm calling the "large gauge transformations" are a copy of the gauge group acting on the boundary theory.  In the holographic superconductor context, for example, a U(1) gauge transformation that doesn't fall off at the boundary would act to change the phase of the condensate.

Comment: There is a related thread here:https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/holography-global-symmetry-in-boundary-corresponds-to-gauge-symmetry-in-bulk.558544/

Comment: Ok to restate what you're saying, the asymptotic symmetries of the theory in the AdS space correspond to global, ungauged symmetries, which will match the CFT symmetries. This I completely agree with. Usually large gauge transformations, for flat spacetime at least, refers to a gauge field that has some nontrivial winding number at infinity.

Comment: Then I no longer understand your initial question.  For me, the fact that these global engaged symmetries match the CFT symmetries is the end of the story.

Comment: No, I think that might be the answer to my question. My confusion stemmed from thinking the asymptotic symmetries of AdS act only as symmetries of the boundary theory and not the bulk. The caveat is that there are cases where the global symmetry matching is geometric, like with N=4 SYM.